# How can I make a RecyclerView behave as the deprecated Gallery?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I basically want to create a [`Gallery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html), but that class has been deprecated for a while, and it suggested I use a different scrolling container.

The closest I've come, after reading various other posts, is a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) using a horizontal [`LinearLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html), and a [`LinearSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html).

This gets me 90% of the way there.

However, if you look at this screenshot of a simple [`Gallery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) from the old API demos, the one obvious missing component is that the first and last views also need to snap **to the center**

How do I do this with a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)?

[image: Gallery demo]

Comment: [Try `LinearSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html). See [this blog post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html) for more.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm already using `LinearSnapHelper`.

It does not solve the problem of snapping the first/last items to the center.  It keeps them at the left/right edge.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying close enough attention. That may require a custom `LayoutManager`, to know that it can scroll past each end to the point where the first/last view is centered. You might look into how pull-to-refresh add-ons for `RecyclerView` work, to see how they convince their `LayoutManager` to scroll past the natural start point.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a [`Space`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/Space.html) to the beginning and end, forcing the width to be half the width of the [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

This seems to have accomplished what I want, though I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setSpaceCount method with horizontal scrolling for achive your requirements something like this :

```
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
 mLayoutManager.setSpaceCount(2);
 yourrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And add scrolling in xml code 
     android:scrollbar="horizontal"